# Imwrite format output filename

Tags: c++, string, string-formatting

I have this piece of code down below:
ImageFile is the file that i saved. And i want to save image with specific name

```
char x[] = "Grey";
imwrite( format("ImageFile-%s.png", x), gray_image);
```

Exampele ImageFile=test.png and output should be test-Grey.png So the
output file name i want to be the initial name of file + string Grey
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `sstream`.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
// other includes
int main()
{
   //other codes
   std::string x{"Grey"};
   std::stringstream ss; 
   ss << "ImageFile-" << x << ".png";
   imwrite(ss.str(), gray_image);
}
```

Comment: I want to print the first name of file so your code will print the output ImageFile-Grey and i want to print NameOfFile-Grey.png so input is test.png and output test-Grey.png another picture three.png should be three-Grey.png your code give me ImageFile-Grey and images have different names..thx a lot

Comment: Then just change the value of `x`. For example, let x is your file name. Then do like this, `ss << x << "-Grey.png"`;

Comment: this is not working my output with this code ss << x << "-Grey.png"; is Grey-Grey.png